# How to set selection in a TableViewer to a specified index?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a `TableViewer` in a `view` of my RCP application. The `TableViewer` has a `List` of `objects` as input. Is it possible to make a `selection` for a particular object using the index of the object in the List that I set as input to the `TableViewer`? For example, I want to set a default selection to the third object every time I open my application. How do I set that selection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
int selection = 5; //row we want to select
tableViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(tableViewer.getElementAt(selection)),true);
```

Thanks to [http://andy.ekiwi.de/?p=1040](https://web.archive.org/web/20131025205016/http://andy.ekiwi.de/?p=1040).

Comment: it will work properly but how to invoke the selection event with that , I want to draw a UI based on the selection, Thanks